# IIS 8.5 Prompting for Credentials with Windows Authentication

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

I'm getting a prompt for credentials on a website in IIS 8.5 running on Windows 2012 that I cannot explain.

App Pool is running under a custom identity that is a member of **Administrators** and **IIS_IUSRS** on the server.

I have the following setting on the Web Site:

```
Anonymous Authentication = Disabled
ASP.NET Impersonation = Enabled
Windows Authentication = Enabled
useAppPoolCredentials = True
```

My web.config has:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

I've ruled out folder security by temporarily granting Full Control to Everyone.

The real weird part is that I have the same App Pool, Web Site, and Folder setup on another node in my NLB cluster and it does not prompt for credentials.

I've also compared ApplicationHost.config files between the two servers and did not find any significant differeneces.

Where else could there be a difference between the two servers?

Update from questions in comments:

The HTTP status code is 401.2.5. FailedReqLog:

```
<failedRequest url="http://url-myapp.com:80/"
               siteId="4"
               appPoolId="myapp"
               processId="14368"
               verb="GET"
               authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE"               
               activityId="{8000002B-000E-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="401.2"
               triggerStatusCode="401.2"
               timeTaken="0"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
```

- AppPool is in Integrated mode
- It does allow after entering credentials

Comment: Your custom identity shouldn't be a member of IIS_IUSRS (it gets that by default), it shouldn't have Admin rights either, unless it absolutely needs it.  As for things to check is whether the site is part of the Intranet Zone and the SPNs for the hostname.   You don't mention:  Does it let you into the server after it prompts?  What OS/Browser are you using to connect with.

Comment: Before diving too deep, learn the status/sub-status that triggers the prompt from IIS log files, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Only then there is something to discuss.

Comment: did you cross check the managed pipeline mode ? are both on classic or integrated mode ? as impersonate is set true, assuming both on classic mode and in that case cant you disable the windows authentication in the above to solve ?